# What size is my iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone

I always thought my iPhone 4 was only 8GB in size, does this mean it is 16GB?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you do have a 16 GB iPhone. The other 2.2 GB are taken up by iOS, etc. See [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2475086?start=0&tstart=0) for more information.

Your model, MC676LL, confirms this: it indicates that you have a Black 16 GB iPhone on Verizon. See [this Bestbuy page](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Apple%26%23174%3B+-+iPhone%26%23174%3B+4+with+16GB+Memory+Mobile+Phone+-+Black+%28Verizon+Wireless%29/2024814.p?id=1218306505021&skuId=2024814&contract_desc=) for more info. The 8 GB phones have different model numbers.

Comment: Why is mine 13.5 GB instead of 13.8 GB?

Answer (score 3):

Yep, looks like it's a 16GB. The reason you see a "Capacity" value less than 16GB is that the remainder of the space is used by the phone's operating system, so isn't available for your use.

AFAIK, before the introduction of the iPhone 4S, and the "low-end" 8GB model of the iPhone 4 at a reduced price, all iPhone 4 models were 16GB or higher. So if your phone is older than October 2011, there's no way it could be 8GB.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you have a 16Gb iPhone right there.  If it was 32Gb then the capacity would show as 28.5Gb.

You may have been confused because (perhaps) the currently selling iPhone 4 tops out at 8Gb, but if you got one when it was the most recent model (i.e. before the 4S) then it came in 8/16/32 capacities.

The actual available capacity as compared with the nominal capacity is always less, as the operating system and default apps all take up some of the avaliable space, as well as setting some aside for emergency use.  It's possible to fill an iPhone such that it says 0bytes free, and still be able to take and store a screenshot of that message... - the usage stats are not necessarily to be relied upon.

Comment: 32gb iphone4? From where?

Comment: They were commonly available. Maybe not in all countries but certainly in the US and UK. Check any wiki page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_4

Answer (score 0):

There are only 3 sizes available for the Verizon iphone4 ([reference](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3939))--8, 16, and 32 GB.  Yours is clearly the 16GB.  Apparently, Apple shows capacity as *total-capactiy minus the size of iOS*.