# I lost 2.3 GB after unjailbreak my iPhone 4s

Tags: jailbreak, iphone

I just unjailbreak my iPhone 4s to the original 5.1.1 version. 
I notice the devise is now SUPER slow and also I noticed that the storqage capacity lost 2.3 GB !!

I have 16 GB iPhone 4s and iTune showing [Capacity 13.62 (.31 other) (13.4 free)]

The way I jaibreaked my iPhone is by 
- downloading 5.1.1 from iTune 
- enter the DFU mode, (power button and home button for 10 sec then only home button for 8 sec)
- click restore

How can I unjailbreak my devise in the correct way? (if I did it wrongly)
What is the reason for losing the storage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54710/what-size-is-my-iphone-4 - the question itself is different but the answers there answer this question as well.

Comment: Great - glad that helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @gtm said

"Possible duplicate of [Apple site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54710/)  - the question itself is different but the answers there answer this question as well"

Answer (score 1):

Whether you're JailBroken or not, and regardless of if you've ever been, you'll never actually see the full 16GB on your iPhone. Part of that 0.31GB of "Other" that iTunes reports are the remnants of the JailBreak. Restore iOS again, and then "Set up as a new phone" when going through the activation process. You'll never gain back that 2.3GB, because that's what iOS is using to store the operating system. To be more detailed, the 13.62GB of capacity is *only* the capacity of the User's partition on `/var/mobile/`. The other 2.3GB is given to `/` (the System partition).

Comment: I did. unfortunately the same thing happened.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't understand my answer. The 2.3GB that you're missing is being taken up by iOS itself.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the traces from the jailbreak, try to restore the device as a New Device" instead of restoring from the back up and see if you still lost that 2.3GB. I have read this somewhere on the internet, if I can remember correctly it is from macrumors forum.